# CSS - matrix of floated items

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: the question in picture form]

Layout 0 shows how I can achieve this layout with a simplified view of the css.
I need help / suggestions / ideas on how to created layouts 1 and 2.
The blocks can be rendered in any order and they are fixed width (either 25% or 50% respectively - as in layout 0)...spanner in the works is they dont have a predefined height.

I would much prefer a css only solution each layout will have its own parent/container div so if positioning is best for one row and floating better for another then so be it.

Answers on a postcard... thanks all

P.S. can I avoid answers that refer me to js librarys like http://masonry.desandro.com/ for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap 2 columns in a div (2 small divs in 1 big with `width: 25%`) and make them all `float: left` (except divs which are wrapped).

Comment: I have picked this as the answer to my question - though it doesn't show an example of the solution, it is the cleanest none script or fixed position way of dealing with this. Hats of to you Pavel and I feel ashamed I didn't see the obvious sooner. Again I really appreciate everyone's answers all are on the money - and are totally valid. Appreciate your thoughts all, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Position the elements within the container absolute, and you can place them wherever you like by just setting the placement with CSS, someting like this :

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2FeSe/1/)

Comment: This is a great solution - agreed, was hoping for something a little more self calculating. Great answer and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with just floats, although in layout 1 you would have to apply a little margin 'trick' (unless i'm overlooking something)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcHAN/)

Perhaps a little more difficult to understand at first glance. I'm just not a big fan of positioning absolute if it is not absolutely required. Though in this case I have to admit @adeneo solution is probably the cleanest way to go.

Comment: nice - I like the left right floats, only issue I have here is the "up" negative margin. In my real world case that would be a varying amount and would require script to fix. Great answer none the less and I hope helps someone out along the way, really really appreciate everyones time on this.